# Is it possible to return a closure that is stored in self?

Tags: rust

I'm using a trait to implement something like the [template method pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern). During parts of the algorithm execution, I'd like it to be able to invoke a callback to report its progress. The way I've been trying to make this work is by storing a `Fn()` on my structs that implement the trait, and then providing a `get_callback` method to provide the callbacks to the default methods on the trait. Unfortunately it's not working.

I suspect the solution will involve some combination of putting the callback in a `Box` and possibly returning a reference, but I haven't been able to get it to work. Here's a minimal non-working example:

```
trait MyTrait<T: Fn()> {
    fn default(&self) {
        let cb = self.get_callback();
        cb();
    }

    fn get_callback(&self) -> T;
}

struct MyStruct<T: Fn()> {
    callback: T,
}

impl<T: Fn()> MyTrait<T> for MyStruct<T> {
    fn get_callback(&self) -> T {
        self.callback
    }
}

fn main() {
    let x = MyStruct { callback: || {} };
    x.default();
}
```

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of borrowed content
  --> src/main.rs:16:9
   |
16 |         self.callback
   |         ^^^^ cannot move out of borrowed content
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is nothing special about the closure here. Your problem is this:

```
fn get_callback(&self) -> T {
    //          ^ you are borrowing self
    //                    ^ but you are not returning a reference
    self.callback
    //   ^ so callback needs to be moved out
}
```

A simple solution would be to clone the closure instead:

```
impl<T: Fn() + Clone> MyTrait<T> for MyStruct<T> {
    fn get_callback(&self) -> T {
        self.callback.clone()
    }
}
```

Cloning closures is only stable as of Rust 1.26 [(see playground example)](http://play.integer32.com/?gist=8339b21b87883418ab94332f0926e3bf&version=beta).

Another solution would be to actually move out:

```
impl<T: Fn()> MyTrait<T> for MyStruct<T> {
    fn get_callback(self) -> T {
    //              ^ no reference
        self.callback
    }
}
```

This [works on stable](http://play.integer32.com/?gist=a7d3d7c3fa6752941ab0235d39c8ee90&version=stable) but requires a few other changes and modifying the trait.

But most likely, the solution you want is to [return a reference to the closure](http://play.integer32.com/?gist=9432aada886fee78b8857eec8d21f99e&version=stable):

```
fn get_callback(&self) -> &T {
    &self.callback
//  ^ there
}
```

But this also requires to change the trait.

Comment: @Shepmaster do you keep a list of questions you have to update on every Rust update? :D

Comment: I use my friend Google: `site:stackoverflow.com rust 1.26`. I also sometimes watch the PRs to [RELEASES.md](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/RELEASES.md), then search for relevant Q&A for stabilized features. There's a vocal contingent of people who complain that Stack Overflow (with and without Rust) has "only outdated information", so I try to kill them with kindness.